# How to get Limit cycle oscillation from the following differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following differential equation

```
r = 1.4;
b = 0.36;
k = 0.4;
\[Epsilon] = 0.1;
a = 10;
sol[t_] = 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == -2 x [t] + r (k + 1) y[t] + 2( k + 1) p[t],
   y'[t] == -(2 k + 1)/(k + 1) x[t] + r k y[t] + (2 k + 1) p[t],
   z'[t] == b p[t],
   \[Epsilon]  p'[t] == 1/(k + 1) x[t] - z[t] - (1 + a) p[t] + a,
   x[0] == 0.1, y[0] == 0.5, z[0] == 0.2, p[0] == 1.3}, {x, y, z, 
   p}, {t, 0, 500}]

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[t_], {t, 200, 400}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

With these parameter values a limit cycle oscillation should appear. However I am not getting any limit cycle. Please help me to rectify the problem.

Comment: If I change your code to `sol=NDSolve[...{x[t],y[t],z[t],p}...][[1]]; ParametricPlot3D[ {x[t],y[t],z[t]}/.sol, {t,0,500}, PlotRange->Full]` then I do get a visible plot. That is as close to your code I can get and not have what I think are errors. If I restrict that to a 2D plot with `ParametricPlot[ {x[t],y[t]}/.sol, {t,0,500}, PlotRange->Full]` then I get a very different plot. That doesn't address your limit cycle issue, but it should get you to the point where you can actually see a plot.

Comment: This looks like a linear system, but limit cycles are a nonlinear phenomenon (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235687/question-about-limit-cycles-and-linear-systems).  Why do you think there is a limit cycle to be found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With $r=3.25$, $b=2.36$, $k=0.14$, $ϵ=1000$, and $a=0.01$ your "limit cycle" appears.

```
r = 3.25; b = 2.36; k = 0.14; ϵ=1000; a = 0.01;

sol[t_] = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -2 x[t] + r (k + 1) y[t] + 2 (k + 1) p[t], 
        y'[t] == -(2 k + 1)/(k + 1) x[t] + r k y[t] + (2 k + 1) p[t], 
        z'[t] == b p[t], ϵ p'[t] == 1/(k + 1) x[t] - z[t] - (1 + a) p[t] + a, 
        x[0] == 0.1, y[0] == 0.5, z[0] == 0.2, p[0] == 1.3}, {x, y, z, p},
        {t, 0, 2000}];

First[ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol[t_], 
        {t, 0, 2000}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.002]}, 
        LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Small], PlotPoints -> 1000, 
        BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]]

Plot[x[t] /. sol[t_], {t, 0, 500}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.002]}, 
        AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Small, Arrowheads[0.03]], 
        LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Small]]
```

Phase portrait and time series
[image]

Calling it the limit cycle is an abuse of language. It is a center. Only in piecewise linear systems is it possible to see limit cycles.

Answer (score 2):

If you rationalize all parameters, you can solve the dgls analytically.

```
rat = Rationalize[{x'[t] == -2 x[t] + r (k + 1) y[t] + 2 (k + 1) p[t],
        y'[t] == -(2 k + 1)/(k + 1) x[t] + r k y[t] + (2 k + 1) p[t], 
        z'[t] == b p[t], \[Epsilon] p'[t] == 
          1/(k + 1) x[t] - z[t] - (1 + a) p[t] + a, x[0] == 0.1, 
        y[0] == 0.5, z[0] == 0.2, p[0] == 1.3}, 0];

sol = DSolve[rat, {x, y, z, p}, t];
```

You need very high workingPrecision for higher t.

```
plxyzp = Plot[
           Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t], p[t]} /. First@sol], {t, 0, 20}, 
           WorkingPrecision -> 1000, PlotRange -> All, 
           PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Magenta}]
```

[image]

Comment: What does dgls mean?

Comment: Have a guess! (just: differential equations.  My mixed german-english abreviation)